# Is there a way to find out who was previously assigned an IP via RRAS VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rras

I need to figure out who had a specific IP for an event from yesterday that was connected through our RRAS VPN. Are any logs or anything else where I can find this information?

I've looked at Event Viewer but can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found them at c:\Windows\System32\LogFiles - The RRAS logs are in form INI####.

Also of note,  you need to have logging turned on for RRAS if you want this to work properly. Directions on how to do so are over here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee922651(v=ws.10).aspx